# Opacity and Plot

Tags: plotting

I have the following function :

```
Plot[-2Cos[ Sqrt[50]/2 Sin[theta]] - 2,  {theta, 0, Pi/2}, 
     PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5], AxesLabel -> {θ, E[θ]}]
```

My problem is that I don't want a constant opacity (here 0.5) for this function but I want opacity as a function of theta (e.g : opacity = Sin[theta]) and I don't know how to do it with Mathematica. Is there a way to do this?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Geoffroy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like:

```
Plot[-2 Cos[Sqrt[50]/2 Sin[theta]] - 2, {theta, 0, Pi/2}, PlotStyle -> Thick,
 ColorFunction -> (Opacity[Sin@#, Blue] &),
 AxesLabel -> {\[Theta], E[\[Theta]]}]
```

[image]

You can also make the line color vary with `theta` while opacity varies with `Sin@theta`:

```
Plot[-2 Cos[Sqrt[50]/2 Sin[theta]] - 2, {theta, 0, Pi/2}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[.02],
 ColorFunction -> (Opacity[Sin@#, ColorData["Rainbow"][#]] &), 
 AxesLabel -> {\[Theta], E[\[Theta]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: In the first code block, shouldn't the `ColorFunction` option be just `ColorFunction -> (Opacity[Sin@#, Blue] &)`?

Comment: thank you `Taiki` -- cut/paste glitch.

Comment: Thank you for your very quick answer kguler ! :)

Comment: @GeoffHudson, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.